# terms and prep for old style doorknobs

Tags: doors, carpentry, doorknob

I like the look of old-fashioned doorknobs with a small rosette.  I'm getting some new doors and thinking about boring and mortising them myself. My plan is to find old knobs, rosettes, locksets from eBay and various building salvage stores.

I'm having a hard time finding any info online about how to do this.  When I search for "small bore" door materials, I only find results talking about how to update an old, small-bore door to a new 2.5 inch bore hole for modern hardware. In my experience, this sort of issue is usually overcome by knowing the exact terminology used by collectors or vintage enthusiasts.

Can anyone on this forum point me to materials for vintage or period house restoration that talks about prepping doors for smaller, old-fashioned rosettes?

Comment: The terminology varies by area and even with generations. Trying to convert the older style solid shaft knob to a modern one requires totally different hardware. Back when I did this work there were a few old guys that had saved the old “junk” and were making a fortune. That was prior to the internet, you may be able to find what you are looking for by googling remodel parts but I know there were 3 different names for leg/taper attachments for claw footed tubs, there are probably dozens for door hardware as there are more options.

Comment: product reccomendatiojns are off topic,  but all the lockset stuff should be available new,  eg: mortice sets for security and tubular sets for privacy.

Comment: Why would you prep the door before acquiring the hardware? Acquire the hardware, measure on-site, and then install it would be the smarter way of doing this.

Comment: What kind of "prep", exactly, are you thinking needs to be done? Are you talking about drilling/mortising the door slab, or something else entirely?

Comment: > Why would you prep the door before acquiring the hardware?...  I wouldn't.  But I'm trying to figure out the names for these old-style parts so that I can source them.  Or, if the project isn't feasible, I'll order pre-bored doors ready to go for modern parts.

Comment: > 
What kind of "prep", exactly, are you thinking needs to be done? Are you talking about drilling/mortising the door slab, ...  Exactly this.

Comment: sounds like you want "mortise locks"; the fancy term for "old-style knobs". They fit in (drumroll) _mortises_ instead of the newer/easier 2.5" through holes.

Comment: > sounds like you want "mortise locks"; the fancy term for "old-style knobs".... Thanks!  Where you see them without the skeleton keyhole (a hallway door, for example), do you use the same hardware but just bury the locking part in the door without exposing it?

Comment: Seems like they're going by "salvaged", "reclaimed", "antique", "vintage", "victorian", etc... There's no single special term because quite simply they were referred to as doorknobs when they weren't vintage. See https://www.ebay.com/itm/antique-crystal-round-door-knob-handle-lot-salvage-reclaimed-victorian/284205053484 and https://www.ebay.com/itm/Large-Lot-of-Vintage-GLASS-DOORKNOBS/333903993632